# Would asking about the rigor of the CDC fall under the "inner workings of research departments" scope of this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

I wanted to ask a question about why this page on the CDC does not have rigorous citations (but only generic content sources) that I would expect to be part of a scientific organization:
https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/your-health/reinfection.html.

I am not quite sure which exact stack exchange to ask it on, but my question was going to be this:
"Why does this CDC page on reinfections not have directly sourced citations?", and I wanted some input on whether this was in scope for Academia stack exchange.

Thank you for you input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDC says

> As the nation’s health protection agency, CDC saves lives and protects people from health threats. To accomplish our mission, CDC conducts critical science and provides health information that protects our nation against expensive and dangerous health threats, and responds when these arise.

I think only questions about the "science" part of the operations would be considered academic and potentially on topic.  Other aspects of CDC operations are not academic.  Your question is about the "health information" and not the "science."

Many other organizations also have both academic and nonacademic operations.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that question falls under our scope. Those CDC pages are advice for broad public consumption - they are not journal articles that would use citations. Further, how a US Federal agency chooses to write on their web site is not in scope for Academia SE.